# Number 0 not removed after country code intl-tel-input

Tags: angular, phone-number, libphonenumber, intl-tel-input

I'm using the intl-tel-input library for phone number validation.

One thing I notice is that I can put a 0 after the country code for an international number like this:

[libphonenumber](http://libphonenumber.appspot.com/phonenumberparser?number=%2B330600000000&country=FR&geocodingLocale=fr&_sm_au_=iVVjtNPn0JsRZNR5)

[image]

As you can see, the phone number is valid and the 0 is automatically stripped with the international format.

I tried to send myself a message with the 0 + the code area and I received the message.

I would like to know for sure that is the user enter his phone number with the 0 with the code area in a form, that we will be able to send him a phone message anyway and that the number won't be invalid. Or do you think I need to code a method to remove the 0 automatically ?

Hope I was clear enough and thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same question, I stumbled over your post. We have issues were calling the number with the '0' in between does not work, even if it is recognized as valid by libphonenumber.

I just did an additional test with SMS. Also here, the SMS with '0' in the number could not be sent.

Example:

- +4179xxxxxxx works
- +41079xxxxxxx does not work

So to answer your question: No, you cannot be sure that numbers with the '0' in between will work in all cases. We now use the E164 format after the number was recognized as valid.

Comment: @Phillipp, I'm also getting this zero appended, is there any way to remove this?

Comment: Yes, as written, use the E164 format after parsing the number with libphonenumber. It gives you the phone number without the '0' between country code and the rest of the phone number.